# Getting data for user based on JWT in Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

This question is half about my code specifically, and half about the high-level view of actually getting data for a particular user from a node API.

So I have user signup/signin all working fine, and lets say I have a one-to-many mapping between Users and Widgets, so each User can create and delete Widgets from his or her profile page.

So here are my database models:

```
var User = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  hash: String,
  salt: String
  widgets    : [{  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'widget' 
          }], 
});

var Widget = new mongoose.Schema({
  name         : String,
  type         : String,
  description  : String,
});
```

In the user login process, I generate a JWT and use that to save an authorization header on the front-end.

Now my question is two-fold. 1) How do I correctly save widgets so that they are associated with the currently logged in User? and 2) How do I get all widgets associated with a user?

My initial thoughts are something like this:

```
app.get('api/widgets', function(req, res, next){
    // decode authorization header to get user email
    // run database query to return all widgets associated with user email
});

app.post('api/widgets', function(req, res, next){
    // decode authorization header to get user email
    // create widget and update user with widget ID
});
```

Is this the correct idea? And if so, how would I go about decoding the authorization header to get the user's email? Do I need to go through this same process for every object associated with the User? Or is there a faster and more convenient way to do this in Node/Express?

Comment: Yes, you can store user widgets data in jwt, but you will need update it after each add/remove widget operation, and it will require additional logic to synchronize new jwt with the client. Much easest way is to use session.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I was clear in the original question. I don't want to store the widget data in the JWT. I'm just storing the user email in the JWT. By 'update user with widget ID', i meant update the user in the database with the widget ID.

Comment: I think this is correct way. If you use some library to encoded jwt token then it most probably also have some decode function. To save widget simply use save function of widget model `new Widget({ name....}).save(function(err, widget){ update user here using $push operator  })` then to get widgets for the user use `User.findOne(id).populate('widgets').exec(function(err, user){  user here will have an array of widgets, not ids but actual objects from widget collection });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the correct idea?

In my opinion, yes, that is correct.

> And if so, how would I go about decoding the authorization header to get the user's email?

If you're using [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) package, there's a `verify` method that decodes the token. You can even store multiple values in a single token, like e-mail and name. `verify` will decode the token into an object with both properties.

> Do I need to go through this same process for every object associated with the User? Or is there a faster and more convenient way to do this in Node/Express?

Loading those objects on every request is probably the most common method. If you find that this loading process is slowing down your application, you can cache it using [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache) or [Redis](http://redis.io/) (recommended when you have a distributed application cluster).

I also suggest that, instead of decoding the user's token into an email on every route, it's common to use a `catch all route` that decodes the token and store in the `locals`. DRY!

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var token = req.signedCookies.token
  res.locals.user = jwt.verify(token, 'my-secret')
  next()
})
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful.